# Making new line after 4 word, Joptionpane

Tags: java, joptionpane

[image]

I'm trying to create a program that collects 16 words and parts of 4 lines; tips?
Here is my code;
I have solved everything but I can not divided by 4 lines.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Kontroll1 {
  public static ArrayList<String> Words = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void  Registerer(String Ordtildikt){
    int i = 0;
    for (;i<4;i++);
    Words.add(Ordtildikt);
    Words.add("\n");
  }
}
```

It should look like this.

Answer (score 0):

If all the words are in the first string, then you'll need to use a string split operation.

String[] lines = Ordtildikt.split("\n");/each line is an element of the array.

However, if you're trying to repeat code for each word, then your for loop is structured oddly.

```
for (;i<4;i++);
```

You should try to avoid making loops without braces "{ ... }" because it is difficult to read. When you write a loop that ends with a semicolon ";" it specifies that this is the end of the loop code and will run through it and execute 0 actual lines of code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  ...// code to loop here
}
```

However, when you have a loop it repeats a set of code, so you'll be adding the same word to the array, which doesn't look like what you're trying to do. What you want to do is have a counter outside of the method.

```
public static ArrayList<String> Words = new ArrayList<String>();
public int wordCount = 0;
```

Increment the counter after adding each word, and add a new line if it's divisible by 4.

```
public void  Registerer(String Ordtildikt){

    wordCount++;
    Words.add(Ordtildikt);
    if(wordCount%4 == 0){
      Words.add("\n");
      wordCount = 0;
    }
}
```